While change theme mode from setting color are not change in flutter
I'm adding change app theme feature in my app. But not i'm stuck right now. I'm done change app theme inside my app. Like change app theme in Light Mode or Dark Mode is work. But while select System Defualt and change device theme from setting. Colors are not applied. Here the code.
main.dart
void main() async {
  // await GetStorage.init();
  final ThemeController themeController = Get.put(ThemeController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      /*themeMode: ThemeService().theme, // Use the theme mode from the service
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,*/
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeController themeController = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(SettingsScreen());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Obx(()=>Text(
              'Welcome Sir',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                color: themeController.isDarkMode.value
                    ? DarkColors.primary
                    : LightColors.primary,
              ),
            )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Obx(()=>ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Name $index',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: themeController.isDarkMode.value
                          ? DarkColors.listTitle
                          : LightColors.listTitle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    'Salary: \$${index * 1000}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: themeController.isDarkMode.value
                          ? DarkColors.listSubtitle
                          : LightColors.listSubtitle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

theme_controller.dart
class ThemeController extends GetxController {
  var isDarkMode = false.obs;

  void changeThemeMode(ThemeMode mode) {
    if (mode == ThemeMode.dark) {
      Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
      isDarkMode.value = true;
    } else if (mode == ThemeMode.light) {
      Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
      isDarkMode.value = false;
    } else {
      Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.system);
      isDarkMode.value = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    }
  }
}

theme.dart
class LightColors {
  static Color primary = hexStringToColor("#05445E");
  static Color listTitle = hexStringToColor("#523A28");
  static Color listSubtitle = hexStringToColor("#A47551");
}

class DarkColors {
  static Color primary = hexStringToColor("#D4F1F4");
  static Color listTitle = hexStringToColor("#FFFFFF");
  static Color listSubtitle = hexStringToColor("#E4D4C8");
}

Color hexStringToColor(String hexColor, {double transparencyPercent = 100}) {
  // Convert the transparency percentage to a hex string
  int transparencyInt = (transparencyPercent * 2.55).round();
  String transparencyHex = transparencyInt.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0').toUpperCase();

  // Normalize the hexColor string
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = "$transparencyHex$hexColor";
  } else if (hexColor.length == 8) {
    // If hexColor already includes transparency, do nothing
  } else {
    throw FormatException("Invalid hex color format");
  }

  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}

setting_screen.dart
class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeController themeController = Get.find();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Settings')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text('System Default'),
            onTap: () {
              themeController.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.system);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Light Mode'),
            onTap: () {
              themeController.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Dark Mode'),
            onTap: () {
              themeController.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'm using Getx pub in my project
I want when i change device theme while open this app change colors of app.
